# sqlite comma separated integer in a text column

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite text column with comma separated integer like 3,899,550. How can I use this value as an integer? I want to filter by values greater than 1million.

```
select * from table_t where some_func(comma_sep_column) > 1000000?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1,234,567', ',', '') AS INTEGER);
```

The `REPLACE` function removes the `','` and the `CAST` function converts to an integer.

Your code would then be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE CAST(REPLACE(comma_sep_column, ',', '') AS INTEGER) > 1000000;
```

Comment: I can confirm this works as I have had the same issue but with <br/>   `SELECT SUM(commasepcolumn) WHERE TYPE = 'ATYPE'`   style query.  This was especially dangerous as it was only taking the numbers up to the first comma so data was coming back, but it was totally incorrect.